# If $g$ is constant, then must $f$ also be constant?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

> Let $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be entire with $\displaystyle\lim_{|z|\to+\infty}\frac{f(z)}{z}=0$ and $g:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ be given by $g(z):=\frac{f(z)-f(0)}{z}$ for $z\neq 0$ and $g(0):=f'(0)$. If $g$ is constant, then does it follow that $f$ is also constant?

I am doubting if this is true. This is an argument to complete my proof, and I don't know how to prove this statement, if indeed it really is true.

Comment: I am pretty sure that if $g$ is constant, say $g\equiv m$, we can say $f(z)=mz+f(0)$, wht $f$ constant?

Comment: @JetfiRex I'm sorry, I forgot an important hypotesis.

Comment: okay that looks good now. That hypothesis makes m→0 and f constant. (but why you again deleted that ($f(z)/z\to 0$ hypothesis)?)

Comment: @JetfiRex I'm sorry. Someone suggested an edit and it disappeard again.  I'm going to fix it again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $g(z)=c$ for all $c$, then $f(z)=f(0)+cz$ for all $z \neq 0$, and in fact this also holds for $z=0$ as you an easily check. Therefore $f$ might not be constant, but it at worse linear.

Now, we have that $f(z)/z=c+f(0)/z$. This way, we get that
$$ \lim_{|z|\to \infty} \frac{f(z)}{z} = \lim_{|z| \to \infty} c+\frac{f(0)}{z} = c. $$
Therefore, if this limit is $0$, then $c=0$, which implies that $f(z)=f(0)$ is constant.

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot an important hypotesis.

Comment: No worries! I just added a way to conclude with the extra assumption

Comment: Glorious! haha 
How can I see the case that $z=0$?
If $g$ is constant and $g(z)=0$ for all $z\not =0$ then $g(0)=0$?

Comment: When $z=0$, we have that $f(0)=f(0)+c\cdot 0$

Comment: But $g(0)=f'(0)$. I still don't see it

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted your question! So, if $g$ is constant and $g(z)=0$ for all $z\neq 0$, then $f(z)=f(0)$ for all $z \neq 0$, right? Then $f$ is constant, and so its derivative is zero.

Comment: Thank you! I got it and finally I finished my prove. :D